# How to plot curve for each row in dataframe without plotting NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

```
    0   5  15   20   25   30   35  40  45  50
----------------------------------------------
0  85  75  65   52   39   21   12   5   2   0 
1  80  69  52   48   21   12    5   2   0   0  
2  81  68  61   49   32   25   14   4   1   0
3  82  64  43   32   19    5    0   0   0   0
4  79  64  49   41   22    6    2   0   0   0
```

For context, each column, and the numerical title of each column, represents a distance away from a site in feet. And so for each row, I am measuring how a certain value decreases as distance away from a site increases. Each row will be a separate curve. And so I can plot each curve as a separate plot with matplotlib, thus producing 5 separate plots for each curve (row). That part is easy.

However, since I have 0s in each row, and in all but one case multiple 0s, the 0 points will be included in the plots. For the rows with multiple 0s, all 0s get recorded in the plots, and so I have a tail of 0s for these plots, with the x-axis going all the way out to 50 feet. This creates a differently shaped curve than if these plots just had one 0 value. For context, in my data/experiment, there is never any value increasing after 0 is hit, so the tail of additional 0s is not necessary, and only serves to give a troublesome-shaped curve (tail of 0s as opposed to a single 0). And so, the rows with multiple zeros as curves with tails of 0s produces a differently shaped curve than if only one 0 was included in those curves. What I am trying to do is find a way to get rid of those extra zeros in the rows, so that once the curve hits 0, the plot (the x-axis) ends.

The ultimate task I am trying to do here, for context, is to fit different curve equations to these curves. I want to use the curves with only the first hit of 0 included, and not the tail of multiple 0s. I have so far tried to classify the extra 0s as NaN, but when I try to plot this, I just get a `ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs` error.. How can I properly get rid of the extra 0s after the first 0 for each row so that the extra zeros are not represented in the curve plots?

Comment: I'm not sure if this captures all of the cases: 1. `dt = df.replace(0, np.nan).T` 2. `dt.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(10, 10))` 3. [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VgY3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep only the first 0 and not the trail of 0s, you can use numpy's function `nonzero` to find the index of nonzero values and trim the array to include those values plus the first 0. This works for plotting and data manipulation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'0': [85, 80, 81, 82, 79],
                   '5': [75, 69, 68, 64, 64],
                   '15': [65, 52, 61, 43, 49],
                   '20': [52, 48, 49, 32, 41],
                   '25': [39, 21, 32, 19, 22],
                   '30': [21, 12, 25, 5, 6],
                   '35': [12, 5, 14, 0, 2],
                   '40': [5, 2, 4, 0, 0],
                   '45': [2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   '50': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})

# Initiate figure
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=1, sharex='col')

for row in df.index:

    # Get array for plotting
    values = np.array(df.loc[row])
    make_x = np.array([0, 5, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50])

    # Count number zeros values
    number_zeros = len(values) - np.count_nonzero(values)

    # There is more than one 0s - aka there is a tail of 0s in this array
    if number_zeros > 1:
        # Get index of last value that is not nonzero in the array
        end_idx = np.nonzero(values)[0][-1] + 2
        # Note: the +2 is because you want the first 0 after the last nonzero value (so you add +1 to index count) but in python the last index is not included so you want the index after that so that the first 0 is included (another +1, therefore +2)

        # Trim the array to only include one zero
        values = values[0:end_idx]
        make_x = make_x[0:end_idx]

    axs[row].plot(make_x, values)

axs[0].set_ylim([0, 90])
plt.show()
```

And this is the result with only one 0 for each plot:

[image]

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: This looks great and totally captures what I am going after, thank you! Though in trying to run your example I received `NameError: name 'start_idx' is not defined`. I see you defined `end_idx`, but is there a reason `start_idx` is not defined, or am I misunderstanding something key here?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, start_idx is 0, I forgot to change it I edited and should be fixed!

Comment: Thank you so much! This example totally works for me and accomplishes the issue I was trying to solve! Though I was still having a bit of difficulty swapping in my actual research data frame which has hundreds of rows and a over 20 columns. I simply swapped it in for `df` in your code, but received a `IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` error specifically point to this line: `end_idx = np.nonzero(values)[0][-1] + 2`. Do you know why this might be happening? I would think I should be able to get your code to work the same way with just a simple data frame swap! hmmm

Comment: Maybe it is because my zeros are written as 0.000000 and 0.0, and not as just 0.

Comment: Hmm yeah I would think a data frame swap would be easy too. On top of my head maybe ```values``` in my code is not being loaded correctly with the new dataframe - perhaps if you print it you can check if it looks like an array? I used ```loc``` but maybe ```iloc``` or maybe df['column_name'][row] could work for you?